# How to save dynamic pyplot as a movie file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've came across this simple example that would help me with my problem:

```
"""
Pyplot animation example.

The method shown here is only for very simple, low-performance
use.  For more demanding applications, look at the animation
module and the examples that use it.
"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(6)
y = np.arange(5)
z = x * y[:,np.newaxis]

for i in xrange(5):
    if i==0:
        p = plt.imshow(z)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        plt.clim()   # clamp the color limits
        plt.title("Boring slide show")
    else:
       z = z + 2
       p.set_data(z)

    print "step", i
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

This shows animation in pyplot interface, but I'd like to save this animation in some movie format, is there a way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to save all the steps as images and then make them into a movie with e.g. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).